# Given a database schema, programmatically generate EF source code

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

We have a project driven by database design.  And when someone makes a db modification, I would like to have my EF code updated.  So, I was wondering if there is a way to programmatically generate EF source code given a database connection string.  I then plan on attaching this generated EF source code to my solution.  I don't need an exact solution right now, but if anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could query the SQL Server system tables and generate code that way, perhaps using XML and XSLT or T4 templates.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189082(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are three approaches to Entity Framework Development: Database First, Model First, and Code First.  You are using Database first.

[Entity Framework Development Approaches](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

I recomend Julia Lerman's book Programming Entity Framework 2nd Edition.

The tutorial I've linked to is for Code First but it has a nice introduction to Repository and Unit Of Work Patterns which you will want to know when using any of the three approaches.